# OpenCv 2.4.7 with QT5

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5

Windows 7, VSC2010

Opencv 2.4.7 Builds fine, mostly works with my application but fontQt and other related Qt text functions cause exceptions (see example below).

Seems like the file(s) that have the necessary code are (at least) window_QT.cpp in sources/modules/highgui/src, but based on where I can set breakpoint but those files don't show up in opencv_highgui project.

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is
>   compiled without QT support) in cv::fontQt, file
>   ........\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 409

The HAVE_QT checkbox was/is checked in the cmake gui (CMAKE 2.8.12.1).  All libraries were found ok (no red left on the GUI)

In build/cvconfig.h I see:

```
/* Qt support */
 #define HAVE_QT5
```

I found this link:[enter link description here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/f856f78ac078e5c4ba67d5856281f3d60b8a4779)

But that looks like it should already be in 2.4.7 based on the later posts to the thread.

I don't really understand how to debug cmake stuff--it seems like maybe the source code is looking for HAVE_QT being defined while maybe only HAVE_QT5 is defined?

Or maybe, (fumbling around where I don't really grog), I see this fragment in highgui\CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(highgui_srcs
    src/cap.cpp
    src/cap_images.cpp
    src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp
    src/loadsave.cpp
    src/utils.cpp
    src/window.cpp
    )

file(GLOB highgui_ext_hdrs "include/opencv2/${name}/*.hpp" "include/opencv2/${name}/*.h")

if(HAVE_QT5)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

  QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(_RCC_OUTFILES src/window_QT.qrc)
  list(APPEND highgui_srcs src/window_QT.cpp src/window_QT.h ${_RCC_OUTFILES})

  foreach(dt5_dep Core Gui Widgets Test Concurrent)
    add_definitions(${Qt5${dt5_dep}_DEFINITIONS})
    include_directories(${Qt5${dt5_dep}_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    list(APPEND HIGHGUI_LIBRARIES ${Qt5${dt5_dep}_LIBRARIES})
  endforeach()
```

Should highgui_srcs include window_QT.cpp?

And help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Dave Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Although you have mentioned that there is no red item in your CMake and you have selected WITH_QT, but in my experience you will need to fill another 7 paths about Qt5 in CMake.

Would you mind checking this

In CMake gui, type **qt** in **Search** field while **Advanced** is selecting.

There should be QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE and some Qt5XXXX_DIR.

Are these all set properly ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have mentioned that yes, 6 Qt5*_DIR variables show up, each with the corresponding correct directory.

Comment: But, I don't see a QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE anywhere